# Golang: when there's only one writer change the value using atomic.StoreInt32, is it necessary to use atomic.LoadInt32 in the multiple readers?

Tags: go, atomic

As the title says. 
basically what I'm wondering is that will the atomic.StoreInt32 also lock read operation while it's writing?

Another relative question:, is `atomic.StoreUint64(&procRate, procCount)` equivalent to `atomic.StoreUint64(&procRate, atomic.LoadUint64(&procCount))`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes those types are protected for both read and write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use atomic operations when you are both loading and storing the same value. The race detector should warn you about this.

As for the second question, if the `procCount` value is also being used concurrently, then you still need to load it using an atomic operation. These two are *not* equivalent:

```
atomic.StoreUint64(&procRate, procCount)
atomic.StoreUint64(&procRate, atomic.LoadUint64(&procCount))
```

The former reads `procCount` directly to pass to `StoreUint64`, while the latter passes a copy safely obtained via `LoadUint64`.

Comment: So, the answer to the first question is I must use atomic.LoadInt even if there's only one thread write to the variable using atomic.StoreInt? regarding the second question,  the first line reads `procCound` directly, so the problem is the value it reads may be a middle status of being modifying, the value at that time may be nonsense?

Comment: If there are concurrent reads and writes _of any kind_, you need to serialize access with a mutex or atomic operations. The second question is just a restatement of the first, it is unsafe to read `procCount` if it's being modified so the result may be meaningless.